# What forms call a shared function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a project that uses n-layer architecture. In the data layer I have several functions and subs that I call from different forms. I would like to know, for each of these functions or subs (in the data layer), which form calls that function. Sort of project statistics. Is there any in-built tool that I can use to list all forms that call a specific function?

Thanks
CL

Comment: If your UI (forms) is calling the data layer, then your n-tier architecture may not be implemented properly.  Typically, the UI layer should only communicate with the business layer and should not know anything about the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `Shared` function or sub.

These can be called by all children of the class and depending on the accessibility (`Public`, `Private`), can also be called from outside the class by qualifying the classname, ie `MyClass.MySharedSub()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want a list of all forms calling that shared function or sub for e.g., form1 calls func1, form3 calls func1, form10 calls func1. I am looking for a tool/way to list form1, form3 and form10 as the forms calling func1. hope that explains my requirement

Comment: Are you generating these forms? If so, create a `Class` that `Inherits Form`, put the sub or function in that class as a `Protected Sub`. It is now available to all your forms, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tools available for code analysis.

1. [Static Code Analysis](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63872/Static-Code-Analysis)
2. [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html) - To visualize a call sequence, choose ReSharper | Inspect | Outgoing Calls or ReSharper | Inspect | Incoming Calls, or use the Inspect This shortcut feature.